# Al añadir contenido a un archivo txt mediante un script .bat, no sucede nada

Tags: cmd, powershell

Tengo un problema al pasar contenido de un archivo txt a otro mediante este código:

```
for /f "delims=" %%G in (myfile.txt) do (
    echo %%G>>temp.txt
)
```

Al ejecutar el script, no sucede nada, me di cuenta que al cambiar la codificación del archivo .txt de utf-16 little Endian a utf-8 el código funciona bien, pero no encuentro manera de cambiar la codificación a utf-8 sin que ocurra errores: por ejemplo, usé este comando para pasarlo a utf-8 usando powershell:

```
powershell -Command "Get-Content .\Myfile.txt | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 Myfile.txt"
```

Pero al hacerlo, igual el texto no me dejaba pasar el contenido con el script .bat, y el texto se ve de esta manera:

> E M V L a s t T r a n s a c t i o n

Comment: Si no te importa, podrías borrar el archivo así se crea uno nuevo con la codificación adecuada. Nota que cmd usa por defecto la codificación 1252. Deberías cambiarla a UTF primero (`chcp 65001`). El script también debe ser guardado en esa codificación para que los símbolos se muestren bien.

Comment: Este script lo necesito ejecutar en otros equipos para modificar el mismo archivo en cada uno, y el problemas es que todos estos archivos tienen la misma codificación. O sea, la idea es que pueda pasar el script y en cada equipo funcione igual.